# How to derive $f^{'''}(x)$ using Taylor expansion?

Tags: numerical-methods

I tried doing the difference between the taylor series expansions of $f(x+h)$ and $f(x-h)$, but it didn't reflect the answer that I should get using the third order central divided difference. The approximation for the third derivative using a central difference is 
$$\dfrac{f(x+2h)-2[f(x+h)-f(x-h)]-f(x-2h)}{2h^3}$$
Should I try the expansion of $f(x+2h)+f(x+h)-(f(x)+f(x-h))$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin How do you know which expression to use? And what do you mean by 3 and 1. Is 3 = f(x+2h) and 1= f(x-h)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exist different Taylor expansions but to prove the one you have, you can try this:

- Write the third order expansion of f at x-h and x+h.
- Write the third order expansion of f at x-2h and x+2h.
- Write the difference D1 of the expansions at x-h and x+h
- Write the difference D2 of the expansions at x-2h and x+2h

Here D1 and D2 will look like:

$$ D_1 = hf'+\frac{1}{3}h^3f'''$$
$$ D_2 = 2hf'+\frac{8}{3}h^3f'''$$

To get rid of the $f'$, write 
$$D_2-2D_1 = 2h^3f'''$$

---